# Как посимвольно перебрать строку, чтобы вставить символы в другую?

Tags: c, строки

На ввод дана строка вида a*b'c", где  (0<= a <= 180) (0<= b <= 59) (0<=c<=59)

Нужно вывести три числа a,b и c.

Ввод: 33*14'55"

Вывод:
33
14
55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, используя `sscanf`:

```
int a,b,c;
char s[] = "33*14\'55\"";
sscanf(s,"%d*%d\'%d\"",&a,&b,&c);
printf("%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",s,a,b,c);

printf("%d*%d\'%d\"",a,b,c);
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, а как ввести с разделителем?
Т.е. задача обратная данной. Например даны a , b, c надо вывести строку в виде a*b'c"

Comment: Дописал эту строчку.

Comment: спасибо большое